# RGL Video with movi3ed

Tags: r, ffmpeg, rgl

I am trying to do an animation using the RGL package:

```
plot3d(x, y,z, xlab="PCA 1", ylab="PCA 2", zlab="PCA 3",
       main="MDS PLOT",col=xxx[phenotype$Patient],type="s",radius=0.04)
text3d(x,y,z,as.character(phenotype$contrasts))
movie3d( spin3d(), duration = 10,dir="mds_video",convert=FALSE)
```

The above code is just a Dummy code on the PCA plot I would like to make an animation. However, the png file movie3d generate is highly low resolution. Then I am using ffmpeg to convert the png's to avi or mp4. However, the png files are really really blurry (Far worse than the pictures in the open gl window).  Is there a way to increase the resolution and have a nice animation.
Thanks

Comment: Did that answer help?

Answer (score 2):

`movie3d` will save whatever size of window you have open.  The default rgl window is pretty small, so you're probably just seeing the effect of that, after some later software expands it.

To get higher resolution, just make your window bigger before creating the movie.  You can default to a larger window by running code like

r3dDefaults$windowRect <- c(100, 100, 1000, 1000)

before opening new windows, and then opening them with open3d() (or one of the other *3d functions).